# Draw shapes on canvas one by one, from array with a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, loops, canvas

I'm trying to create a sort of interactive map. Where the user places markers on the canvas to mark a path through the map. Once they're done I want them to be able to press a button that will animate their path, one marker at a time, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I have the user marking the canvas with this code.

getCoords(e) is a function placed elsewhere that detects the mouse coordinates.

```
function draw(e) //mousemove
{  
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, false); 

    var coords = getCoords(e);

    a = coords[0];
    b = coords[1];
    xcor.push(a);
    xcor.push(b); 

    context.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);

    context.beginPath();

    context.arc
    (
        coords[0],
        coords[1],
        10,
        Math.PI*2,
        false
    );

    context.closePath();

    context.fillStyle='blue';

    context.fill();

    if (drawing == true)
    {

        for(i=0;i<drawCoords.length;i++) 
        {

            context.beginPath();

            context.arc
            (
                drawCoords[i].x,
                drawCoords[i].y,
                10,
                Math.PI*2,
                false
            );

            context.closePath();

            context.fill();           

            x = coords[0];  
            y = coords[1];          
            context.beginPath(); 


        for(i=0;i<drawCoords.length;i++) 
        {             
            context.lineTo(drawCoords[i].x,drawCoords[i].y);
            context.stroke();
        }
}

function startSketch(e) //mousedown
{

    var coords = getCoords(e);

    drawCoords.push({x:coords[0], y:coords[1]});
    draw();     
}
```

and then I am trying to loop through that code to animate the path when a button is clicked by  using this code.

```
function playButton() 
{
    drawing = false;

    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, false); 

    (function theLoop (l) 
    {

        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            draw();
            if (--l) 
            {          
                theLoop(l);       
            }
        }, 1000);

    })(drawCoords.length);

}
```

It displays the completed path but I want it to show each step with a delay in between.

I think I may be using the array drawCoords wrong in theLoop function but I can't seem to figure out the righy way to loop through the arrays contents. I've tried re-writing most of the code from draw(); inside the setTimeout function but when I do, nothing at all happens.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

in your code setTimeout will be triggered instantly when the function repeats itself. You can use setInterval to achieve this. If you need a higher quality animation look into requestAnimationFrame().

```
var i = 1;
var animation = setInterval(function() { 
    draw();
    i += 1;
    if(i >= drawCoords.length) {
        clearInterval(animation);
    }
}, 1000);
```